# Draw output bars according to given inputs

Tags: bash, shell

I need a bash script that will get 5 arguments then draw hashes according to each given argument for example the inputs are :

```
8 10 15 5 12
```

the output should be :

```
8: ########
 10: ##########
 15: ###############
  5: #####
 12:############
```

if it's possible to make it vertical it would be better

Comment: Can you share what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vertical bars you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

max=0
for v in $@; do
  if (( $v > $max )); then max=$v; fi;
done

printf "%d  %d  %d  %d  %d\n" $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
for (( i=1; i<=$max; i++ )); do
  for j in $@; do
    if (( $j >= $i )); then
      printf "#  "
    else
      printf "   "
    fi
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `printf` [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf), especially the `%` modifier.

I think it only does padding with spaces, so a possible turnaround is pipe the output into `tr` to replace spaces with your `#` char.

[edit] Actually, the page I linked to has an interesting trick under "*repeating a character (for example to print a line)*" that's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Through python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
with open('/path/to/input/file', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read()
    for i in re.finditer(r'\d+', f):
        print i.group()+': '+int(i.group())*'#'
```